# Python json error: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

I am new to python, and I getting an error and I can't figure it out :`pics = r.json()['data'['photo_list']`
please help to solve this problem, many thanks!

```
# -*-coding:utf8-*-
import re
import json
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import requests
def main():
    headers = {
        'Cookie' : 'SUB=_2AkMhFc9hf8NhqwJRmPoRym_jaI9_ygvEiebDAHzsJxJjHlE47Gaj8oPkdVHDdzd9ToAkUSPIsxRx; SUBP=0033WrSXqPxfM72-Ws9jqgMF55529P9D9WWM2vn1KHS_k1aSj6DvSDWv; SINAGLOBAL=7552724259118.417.1447641174437; ULV=1447691774405:2:2:2:6434341784127.688.1447691774390:1447641174455; YF-Page-G0=7f5e11c19f51c6954c5e18e40c0b1444; _s_tentry=-; Apache=6434341784127.688.1447691774390; USRANIME=usrmdinst_29"; # Your cookies.',
        'Host':'photo.weibo.com',
        'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Mobile Safari/537.36',
    }
    url = "http://photo.weibo.com/photos/get_all?uid=2215245793&album_id=3555077064049743&count=30&page=1&type=3&__rnd=1503164588496"
    r = requests.get(url,headers = headers)
    pics = r.json()["data"]["photo_list"]
    for x in pics :
        name = x["pic_name"]
        src = "http://wx1.sinaimg.cn/large/"+name
        download(name,src)
def download(name,src):
    try:
        urlretrieve(src,'img/'+name)
        print('ok!')
    except Exception as e :
        print(src,'download fail!')

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/python/User/爬取新浪微博.py", line 28, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:/python/User/爬取新浪微博.py", line 15, in main

    raise JSONDecodeError(errmsg, string, idx)
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `print(r.status_code, r.content)` you would see that you get 404 response with some html. This is the reason `JSONDecodeError` fails.

Answer (score 0):

print(r.status_code) = '404 response' and print(r.content) = 'File not found'